# Out of memory when page loads

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have uploaded bunch of data from excel to sql database.
when the page loads after uploading the data, the browser says 'out of memory'. Didn't have any issue when was uploading data around 100 rows.

[image]

```js
<script>
    var table = $('#basic-datatables').DataTable({
        searching: false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No Record Found"
        }
    });

</script>
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
@{
    ViewData ["Title"] = "Index";
}
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table text-center table-striped table-hover" id="basic-datatables" cellspacing="1">
        <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.firstname</td>
                    <td>@item.middlename</td>
                    <td>@item.lastname</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-button-action"> 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-lg">
                            <a asp-controller="Exposure" 
                               asp-action="ViewDetails" 
                                asp-route-Identifier="@item.identifier" 
                                class="fas fa-users" 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                data-placement="top" 
                                title="View Accumulation">
                             </a>
                          </button>
                          <button type="submit" 
                                  class="btn btn-link btn-lg" 
                                  id="Edit" 
                                  onclick="Edit(@item.id)">
                             <a class="fas fa-pencil-alt" 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                data-placement="top" 
                                title="Edit Session">
                            </a>
                           </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
public IActionResult Index()
{
   objDbData= _db.Database;
   return View(objDbData);
}
```

Comment: Limit returned records `objDbData = _db.Database.Take(100); `

Comment: got it. actually this is what i did now and it worked :D thanks Svyatoslav Danyliv